# PHP - Find array inside array. Do check -=if array contains other specific array=-

Tags: php, arrays, search, find, contains

How we can do check for availability of specific array inside array?

For example we have multidimensional array:

```
$arr = array(
  array(1,2,3),
  '12',
  true,
  4,
  array(
    'name1' => array(1,2),
    array(
      'some1' => array(99,98,96),
      4
    ),
    array(4,4)
  )
);
```

And we want do check for array(99,98,96), do exist it inside our $arr?

Comment: Well, there obviously is no ready to be used function for this. So you will have to implement your own. Did you try that? Please post the code you have so far and explain what is not working as expected. We need a _specific_ question to be able to help. We are not here to write your code for you, sorry.

Comment: This is very abstract logic, and I don't believe, that nobody can share some small snippet of code.

Comment: Voting to close this question. I recommend you hire a payed programmer to do your work for you. We are here to help you with _your_ code, not to write your code for you. That is _clearly_ explained in the meta questions explaining what this page is about.

Comment: @Vital yes, i do agree with what arkascha saying .. you at-least need to come up with something which you have tried and we will go through and can give u suggestion or solution for sure.

Comment: I understand you fully. But, when we know this is not very specific question where all small questions must be explained, but question with only abstract logic which can be useful for everyone in everyday work: I don't think we must close this topic. I don't ask people to write some huge app, but just show small native snippet of code to understand better which brains using better solution to solve my small question.

Comment: You are asking for someone to write a custom function for you. Consider researching better and at least attempt to solve your problem. No effort = no answer.

Comment: I've searched on current website of similar question, but I did not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code from source [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I hope this will work

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function findRecursive($arr, $find)
{
    foreach ($arr as $match)
    {
        if (is_array($match))
        {
            if ($match == $find)
            {
                return true;
            } else
            {
                if (findRecursive($match, $find))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```